# Find the general solution to the differential eq:$ (x^2 + y^2) + xyy'=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution to the differential equation:

$$(x^2 + y^2) + xyy'=0.$$

Hmm, I'm not sure what method to use to solve this but it looks like I can solve it with separable method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing by $xy$, 
$$\frac x y + \frac y x = -y'$$

This motivates the substitution $u = y/x$, so that

$$y = xu \implies y' = u + xu'$$

Substituting into the equation then gives

$$\frac 1 u + u = -u - xu'$$

and simplifying leads to

$$xu' = -\frac{1 + 2u^2}{u}$$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: hmm im not sure how I can get the fraction and du on the same side? and also can you explain how u got that under where it says substitution? but it looks like I get something with lnx? :P

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to writing $$\frac{u u'}{1 + 2u^2} = -\frac 1 x$$ and then writing $u' = du/dx$ gives you a completely separated equation. Writing $y = xu$ is just algebra from the substitution, and then I differentiated with the product rule.

Comment: ahh cool thanks, but I guess I have to use the same method for 2x + y^2 + 2xyy'=0

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to @T.Bongers great answer.

Define $u=y^{2}$ we can reduce the equation to 
$$
\frac{x}{2}\frac{du}{dx} + u = -x^{2}\implies \\
\frac{du}{dx} + \frac{2}{x}u = -2x
$$